# Excel Date and Time format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format

I am having trouble with datetime format. I used custom format in order to get my data to read as 01/02/2016 05:33:23. But instead it is reading as 42401 05:33:23.

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting to set a range to this format just go into the Format option once the range is highlighted; then select "More Number Formats". At the bottom is a "Custom" option, in the entry box type the following:

`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

That should be the correct format setting.